# Select2 not calculating `resolved` width correctly if select is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am using Twitter bootstrap and [the fantastic Select2 plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/).

These are working great, I realized you need to set `{width: 'resolve'}` when initiating Select2 otherwise it looks messed up!.

But I am having an issue with one of my selects, as you can see in the image below, the `Referee Type` select has an incorrect width.

This is caused due to this field being initially hidden, and only becoming visible if *Referee* is selected in the *Group* field.

So, how can I fix this?

[image: Inputs]

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle this way we can take a look at your problem?

Comment: one option is wait until element shown to initialize plugin, another is don't hide `select` but place it offscreen until needed. Demo would help

Comment: I've been using select2 for a while and I usually set the width inline in the element style in the HTML - I know it is not very good practice but Select2 will attempt to copy the element style's width prior to resolving its actual dimensions so it is worth a shot. In that case you can remove `width: 'resolve'`.

Comment: try adding inline width with "!important".

Answer (score 37):

`Select 2` is smart enough to recalculate it's size if only you set it in the `select` tag. Like so:

`<select style="width: 100%"></select>`

CSS formatting on classes would not work!

Read more in "[Responsive design - Percent width](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)"

Comment: In addition to saying that this is the only correct answer, I feel like adding that the behavior is different between Firefox and Chrome for some reason. Kudos anyway!

Comment: You are very welcome. Did you notice any difference between Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: This definitely works, but may I know what makes this issue?

Comment: This works for the select, but not for the placeholder inside. If there is a long placeholder, it gets cut off

Answer (score 20):

You can set the width in the `<select>` element like so:

```
<select style="width:260px">
```

Until you find the desired width that you're looking for. In fact, the examples on the official select2 plugin site are done in this way.

However, if you're intent upon staying away from inline styles, you can always simply override select2's CSS and target the resulting container.

```
.select2-container {
  width: 260px;
}
```

Comment: omg this was driving me crazy, ugh the simplest things are always overlooked. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 20):

I solved my similar problem with simple CSS:

```
.select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer.  Easiest to implement also.

Comment: It works for all cases (if element is hidden within a hidden parent and also if the element itself is hidden). No need to check any external cases.

Comment: This interferes with other select boxes negativley in my instance

Comment: in my case, this causes me a vertical scroll because the span is not in the very left of the monitor and it's taking 100% of the <body> width which causes an overflow width –

Answer (score 8):

Instead of invoking `select2()` on the Referee Type when the page loads, invoke `select2` after showing Referee Type for the first time. This way, the select will be visible (with a proper width), and the `'width': 'resolve'` option should work. If you provide a small jsfiddle example it would be easier to point this out.

Comment: Does the tricks for ajax render (without quote for width). Thanks.

Comment: THIS IS THE RIGHT ANSWER! :)
My Select2 was working properly till I don't move to a hidden TAB.
From that point width of Select2 was reduced to the selected value.
This is just a BUG, the workaround is to display:block/declare Select2 /display:none during page ready.

Answer (score 6):

Set the style property of `select` element with width 100%

```
<select class="js-example-responsive" style="width: 100%"></select>
```

See [Responsive design - Percent width](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating)

Answer (score 3):

```css
.select2-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Execute this when you unhide controls with Select2 attached:

```
//refresh select2 controls (to correct offscreen size bad calculation)
$("SELECT.select2-offscreen").select2();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could bind a click event to the element that opens you hidden element and set the select2 width there. Worked for me and it's pretty simple. I used the click event because doing it with just 'document ready' wasn't working.

```
$('#click-me').on('click', function(event) { 
   $('.select2').select2({width: '100%'});
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://select2.org/appearance#container-width), you could add the proper width to settings on initialization:

```
$(".js-example-responsive").select2({
    width: '100%' // or 'resolve' or 'style' or 'element' - see docs
});
```

Worked like a charm for me while other recipes didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is to stop `select2` from assigning those `width` and let them be automatic. Comment the following in `select2.full.js` :

For Container:

```
  Select2.prototype._placeContainer = function ($container) {
    $container.insertAfter(this.$element);

      //##!!
      /*
    var width = this._resolveWidth(this.$element, this.options.get('width'));

    if (width != null) {
      $container.css('width', width);
    }*/
  };
```

For Search inside the container:

```
  Search.prototype.resizeSearch = function () {

    //##!!
    /*
    this.$search.css('width', '25px');

    var width = '';

    if (this.$search.attr('placeholder') !== '') {
      width = this.$selection.find('.select2-selection__rendered').innerWidth();
    } else {
      var minimumWidth = this.$search.val().length + 1;

      width = (minimumWidth * 0.75) + 'em';
    }

    this.$search.css('width', width);
    */
  };

  return Search;
});
```

Comment: There's an open issue to fix this here, though at present no patch or response from the maintainer: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4513

Comment: $('select').select2({
    width: 'auto'
});

Answer (score -1):

hack to make it work is to run:

`$('.filter-modal select').css('width', '100%');`
before 
`$('select').select2().`

https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4269

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
.select2-container  {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

also a fixed width

```
.select2-container  {
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Select2 has a strange bug which not "resolve" in the correct way hidden Select2 elements. It's not working place `width: "resolve"` as this is already the default value. Instead the workaround is to show the select2 and hide them suddenly a second later the declaration.

```
$("#div_container_of_select2").show(); //make it visible for a millisecond
$("select[name=referee_type]").select2(); //declare Select2
$("#div_container_of_select2").hide(); //back to darkness
```

This will render correctly the select2.

Answer (score -2):

```
$("span.select2").css("width", "100%");
```